# SQL syntax question

Tags: sql, mysql

SQL syntax question about UPDATE. It would be much easier to ask the question by giving example below:

```
**Payments Table**

ID  user_id  payment_due   payment_made 
1      3        10.0           5.0
1      3        10.0           10.0
1      9        20.0           20.0



**Balance Table**

ID  user_id    current_balance 
1      3            ???
2      9            ???
```

Let say I would like to update the current balance for specific user. What would be the correct and efficient SQL syntax to add all payment dues and subtract it from all payment made for a specific user?

In this case, current_balance for user '3' is 5.0 and for user '9' is 0.0

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
select
   ID,
   user_id,
   (sum(payment_due) - sum(payment_made)) current_balance
from
   PaymentsTable

group by
   ID,
   user_id
```

Comment: This might be the best approach. Don't keep a `Balance` table since the balance would constantly change. You could even turn this query into a view so that it behaves like the `Balance` table.

Comment: Or use a trigger to keep the data in sync.

Comment: as stated above don't keep a Balance table...storing a calculated field (current_balance) breaks the rules of normalization, use the query to get the data on the fly

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I think it is best not to use current balance table

Answer (score 2):

To update your table, use a sub-query:

```
UPDATE Balance_Table b
SET current_balance =
  ( SELECT SUM( payment_due - payment_made )
    FROM Payments_Table p
    WHERE p.user_id = b.user_id
  )
```

Think about the update-approach though. Your `Balance_Table` will be out of sync as soon as `Payments_Table` changes, so you might be better off with actually selecting data from there.

Comment: I suppose he could throw this UPDATE statement in a trigger on the `Payments` table. That would remove some of the discrepancy.

Comment: @cmptrgeekken: Using a trigger would be possible. If there are lots of records in `Payments_Table` but only few records change and results of `Balance_Table` are queried often, then this could be the right approach. Otherwise, just summing up `Payments_Table` would be the easier approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a subquery. Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE
    balance_table b
SET
    current_balance = (SELECT
            SUM(payment_due - payment_made)
        FROM
            payments_table p
        WHERE
            p.user_id = b.user_id)
```